# Is there a DRY way to consolidate same code for RowMappers?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, row

I'm working with JDBC and many of my classes have an inner RowMapper class as following:

```
public class Foo {
  class AppleRows implements RowMapper<Apple> {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = new Apple();
      a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
    }
  }

  class AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse implements RowMapper<Apple> {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = new Apple();   
      a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
      a.setSomethingElse(rs.getString("SomethingElse"));
    } 
  }
}
```

In the above example the line `a.setName(rs.getString("Name"))` is being duplicated. This is just an example but in my actual code there are more than 10 fields like this. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Note: I need to different mappers because I'm using them from some places where I'm joinging the results with another table (fetching more fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `extend` + use `super.mapRow()`...

```
public class Foo {
  class AppleRows implements RowMapper<Apple> {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = new Apple();
      a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
      return a;
    }
  }

  class AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse extends AppleRows {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = super.mapRow(rs, rowNum);
      a.setSomethingElse(rs.getString("SomethingElse"));
      return a;
    } 
  }
}
```

Or simply delegate, if you don't like using inheritance as the mechanism of code reuse:

```
public class Foo {
  class AppleRows implements RowMapper<Apple> {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = new Apple();
      a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
      return a;
    }
  }

  class AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse implements RowMapper<Apple> {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = new AppleRows().mapRow(rs, rowNum);
      a.setSomethingElse(rs.getString("SomethingElse"));
      return a;
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to use inheritance, especially if you can make the inner classes into `static` nested classes, like so:

```
public class Foo {
  static class AppleRows implements RowMapper<Apple> {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = new Apple();
      a.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
      return a;
    }
  }

  static class AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse extends AppleRows {
    public Apple mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Apple a = super.mapRow(rs, rowNum);
      a.setSomethingElse(rs.getString("SomethingElse"));
      return a;
    } 
  }
}
```

The reason I used `static` nested classes here is because there is an implicit reference to an instance of the containing class in non-`static` nested classes that is unused (at least in the current implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Each mapper maps a single row definition.  I wouldn't call this a violation of DRY.

When a single column name is changed in the underlying view for `AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse`, you  only have to change it in one place.

If you refactor this using common code, then you'd be in a strange position if the view supplying `AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse` changes, but the one underlying `AppleRows` does not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to extend to share common functionality.  I'm just typing this, so it may not actually compile.

```
public class CommonBlammy
{
    private CommonBlammy() { } // private constructor to prevent instantiation.

    public static Apple mapRow(final ResultSet resultSet)
    throws SQLException
    {
        Apple returnValue = new Apple();

        returnValue.setName(resultSet.getString("Name"));

        return returnValue;
    }
}

public class AppleRows implements RowMapper
{
    public Apple mapRow(
        final ResultSet resultSet,
        final int rowNumber)
        throws SQLException
    {
      return CommonBlammy.mapRow(ResultSet resultSet);
    }
}

public class AppleRowsJoinedWithSomethingElse implements RowMapper
{
    public Apple mapRow(
        final ResultSet resultSet,
        final int rowNumber)
    throws SQLException
    {
        Apple returnValue;

        returnValue = CommonBlammy.mapRow(ResultSet resultSet);
        returnValue.setSomethingElse(rs.getString("SomethingElse"));

        return returnValue;
    } 
}
```